# Catch Linux user string with regex

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the following text string:

```
user01-s
user01--s
user01
```

The goal is to catch the username from a log event. So I want to catch:

First line: `user01`

Second line: `user01-`

Third line: `user01`

Each line contains a linux user (that might include a `-`). There are some cases where the line ends with `-s` and this shouldn't be part of the username.

So my solution for this is:

`(?:(\S+)-s)|(\S+)`

But I'm wondering if we can catch the username in a better way.

Comment: Without the `|` you could use an optional part `\b(\w+-?)(?:-s\b|$)` https://regex101.com/r/DjiPpE/2

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all but the last dash are part of the username?  Also, is it ONLY "-s" that might appear at the end of the line and need to be excluded?

Answer (score 1):

If the username is on the whole line, you could use a single capturing group with an optional part to match the `-s` part:

```
^([^\s-]+-?)(?:-s)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zfuaB5/1)

If there can be a hyphen present in the username, you could use `\S` and make it non greedy `\S+?`

```
^(\S+?)(?:-s)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x4DWXM/1)

Comment: This doesn't work with the following line for example: `use-r01--s` where the user should be `use-r01-`

Comment: @Steve You could turn it into a non greedy `\S?` like `^(\S+?)(?:-s)?$` https://regex101.com/r/x4DWXM/1

Comment: Or a bit more performant pattern (if a lookahead is supported to not match an empty string) `^(?!$)([^-\s]*(?:-(?!-s$)|[^-\s]*)*-?)[^\s-]*(?:-s)?$` See https://regex101.com/r/Ffh47x/1